# Save tail output to mysql

Tags: mysql, database, linux, save, tail

I'm having a problem, I need to save the tail output to mysql. I can save the output to a file,
Here is the tail command:

```
tail -f file_ | egrep --line-buffered param_ > path_destinty
```

For my application it is necessary to save the information in the time that it is written.

Any tips?

Comment: But what's the problem you are having? Isn't this working?

Comment: This works, but I need to save to mysql insted of a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
 tail -f file_ | \
 grep -E --line-buffered param_ | \
 while read line; do \
 mysql -E -u root -p root -h 127.0.0.1 'INSERT INTO `test`.`test` (`text`, `updated`) VALUES ("'${line}'", NOW());'; done
```

Pipes:

1. tail your file
2. because egrep is deprecated, use grep -E
3. cycle for parsing data and send them to MySQL

Params of MySQL:

```
-E       Execute query
-u       Username
-p       Password for this user
-h       Host/IP
`test`   is the name of the database and table
${line}  our varible with text
```